# text not wrapping in overflow:auto;width:100% div when it is inside a table

Tags: html, css

I have recently come across a strange issue with an overflow auto div inside a table cell (yes I have to keep the table).

The text inside the div will NOT wrap when it is inside the table. If I put the div in another div to wrap, it works perfect.

My temporary solution is to use javascript to force the width but this is poor and does not deal with re-sizing very well.

If anyone has any thoughts I would be happy to hear.

See the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jNZNF/

```
<table style="width: 400px;" border="1">
<tr><td>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue;">
ip\84.23.214.125:27960\name\Ze_Pequeno\password\bs\racered\1\raceblue\0\rate\25000\ut_timenudge\30\cg_rgb\153,0,0\funred\tridente\funblue\katana\cg_predictitems\0\cg_physics\1\gear\FHAOWRA\snaps\20\model\sarge\headmodel\sarge\team_model\james\team_headmodel\*james\color1\4\color2\5\handicap\100\sex\male\cl_anonymous\0\teamtask\0\cl_guid\49B4985AFD5E18C17EAC67AF5A6F4247\weapmodes\00000111220000020000
</div>
</td></tr></table> 


<div style="width: 400px; border:1px solid pink">
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue">
ip\84.23.214.125:27960\name\Ze_Pequeno\password\bs\racered\1\raceblue\0\rate\25000\ut_timenudge\30\cg_rgb\153,0,0\funred\tridente\funblue\katana\cg_predictitems\0\cg_physics\1\gear\FHAOWRA\snaps\20\model\sarge\headmodel\sarge\team_model\james\team_headmodel\*james\color1\4\color2\5\handicap\100\sex\mal e\cl_anonymous\0\teamtask\0\cl_guid\49B4985AFD5E18C17EAC67AF5A6F4247\weapmodes\00000111220000020000
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you, this should do it:

```
<table style="width: 400px;" border="1">
<tr><td>
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue;">
ip\84.23.214.125:27960\name\Ze_Pequeno\password\bs\racered\1\raceblue\0\rate\25000\ut_timenudge\30\cg_rgb\153,0,0\funred\tridente\funblue\katana\cg_predictitems\0\cg_physics\1\gear\FHAOWRA\snaps\20\model\sarge\headmodel\sarge\team_model\james\team_headmodel\*james\color1\4\color2\5\handicap\100\sex\male\cl_anonymous\0\teamtask\0\cl_guid\49B4985AFD5E18C17EAC67AF5A6F4247\weapmodes\00000111220000020000
</div>
</td></tr></table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayAh7/1/

```
<div style="width: 400px; border:1px solid pink">
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue">
ip\84.23.214.125:27960\name\Ze_Pequeno\password\bs\racered\1\raceblue\0\rate\25000\ut_timenudge\30\cg_rgb\153,0,0\funred\tridente\funblue\katana\cg_predictitems\0\cg_physics\1\gear\FHAOWRA\snaps\20\model\sarge\headmodel\sarge\team_model\james\team_headmodel\*james\color1\4\color2\5\handicap\100\sex\mal e\cl_anonymous\0\teamtask\0\cl_guid\49B4985AFD5E18C17EAC67AF5A6F4247\weapmodes\00000111220000020000
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, however, for my case it did not work as I cannot adjust the table properties (did not state that in the question). will accept this answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `word-break:break-all` rule to your table (or div within the table). Since you have essentially one long string (no spaces), the browser won't break it unless you force it to.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jNZNF/4/)**

Comment: this is what ended up working for me - BUT - I feel the correct answer is the "table-layout: fixed;" one as this does not wrap the text but forces it to overflow within the div and does not overflow out of the table.